# Float parent's width in table-cell behavior

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive navbar. The navbar has 3 parts and only the middle part is to stretch on resize.

I apply `display: table;` and `width:100%;` on `header` and `display: table-cell;` to the child elements. `width: 1px;` and `white-space: nowrap;` are added to  `.left` and `.right` to occupy just the space they need to and `width: auto;` is added to `.middle` to allow it to occupy the rest of the width. It works!

The problem is that `.right` has `float`ed children inside and `.right` itself  doesn't have the correct width (the list should all be in one line).

This is my code example:

```css
header {
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.head-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 1px;
}
.left {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.middle {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.middle input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.right {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.right ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="head-cell left">My super Logo</div>
  <div class="head-cell middle">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="head-cell right">
    <nav role='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>  
  </div>
</header>
```

Notice: I don't want to use the `inline-block` behavior and hack the ghost space between the item's. I want to use `float` behavior inside.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? The list in one line?

Comment: yes, i want this on 1 line

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve this using `float` unless you also set a `width` on the `ul` (which I doubt you will want to do):

```css
header {
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.head-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 1px;
}
.left {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.middle {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.middle input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.right {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.right ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 260px;
}
.right ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="head-cell left">My super Logo</div>
  <div class="head-cell middle">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="head-cell right">
    <nav role='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>  
  </div>
</header>
```

This is because `float`s only position themselves next to each other if there is enough room for them to fit.

> If there is not enough horizontal room for the float, it is shifted downward until either it fits or there are no more floats present.

*Floats (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)*

Setting the `li` to `display: inline-block;` is the method I would personally use:

```css
header {
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.head-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 1px;
}
.left {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.middle {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.middle input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.right {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.right ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="head-cell left">My super Logo</div>
  <div class="head-cell middle">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="head-cell right">
    <nav role='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li><li><a href="#">Clients</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>  
  </div>
</header>
```

But, as you have specifically asked for a method not using `inline-block` I would go for `flexbox` instead:

- Add `display: flex;` to `.right ul`. This will tell its children to use the flexbox  model
- As `flex-direction` is set to `row` by default, the `li` will be aligned from left to right
- `flex-wrap` is set to `nowrap` by default, so the `li` will remain on one line

```css
header {
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.head-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 1px;
}
.left {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.middle {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.middle input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.right {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.right ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="head-cell left">My super Logo</div>
  <div class="head-cell middle">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="head-cell right">
    <nav role='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li><li><a href="#">Clients</a></li><li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>  
  </div>
</header>
```